# Finding big-omega of an algorithm for maximum subarray sum

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have an algorithm and I am trying to figure out the best-case scenario (asymptotic notation) for this algorithm that solves the maximum subarray sum problem:

```
-- Pseudocode --

// Input: An n-element array A of numbers, indexed from 1 to n.
// Output: The maximum subarray sum of Array A.

Algorithm MaxSubSlow(A):
    m = 0.
    for j = 1 to n do:
        for k = j to n do:
            s = 0
            for i = j to k do:
                s = s + A[i]
            if s > m then:
                m = s
    return m
```

Looking at the algorithm, using asymptotic notation math it is easy to determine the worst-case scenario (each loop runs, in its worst case, all n times) so the worst-case complexity class would be O(N^3).

However, my textbook states that this algorithm also runs in Big-Omega(N^3) time; that is, the lower bound is equal to its upper bound. It does not offer an explanation as to why, though.

How would you formally calculate and prove this? Do you have to prove that for the algorithm, there is a subset of numbers (i, j, k) such that each loop in the algorithm will run at least n times? If so, how do you do that?

Comment: All you have to do is to evaluate a formula containing 3 nested sums. You can do it by yourself or use tools like wolfram alpha. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28sum+%28sum+%281%29+i+%3D+j+to+k%29+k+%3D+j+to+n%29+j+%3D+1+to+n

Or you can for example use induction to prove that this sum is greater or equal to `1/6 * n`. There is a number of other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, even if you change the input keeping the same size `n`, it performs the same number of operations: the number of operation only depends from the input size, not the specific input. So best and worst case scenario are the same.

The computation of o() is exactly the same as O() in this case